# Script works fine manually but not working on crontab

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cassandra, cqlsh

My script is working manually but not working on crontab.I read all topics about this issue I tried so many things to execute via crontab but didnt work.

My script is below.

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
nodetool status > cqlsh_control.txt
cs1=`more cqlsh_control.txt | awk '{print $1}' | sed -ne 6p | cut -d"%" -f1`
SLACK_ICON=":red_circle:"
if [ "$cs1" != "UN" ]; then

curl -S -X POST --data "payload={\"text\": \"{Cqlsh is not responsing Cassandra2}  \",\"username\":\"CQLSH\",\"icon_emoji\":\"${SLACK_ICON}\"
}" https://hooks.slack.com/services/T05xxxxW/B7xxxxxx09/QdotCzoxxxxxxxHxOsrnjS

fi
```

Comment: When you say 

> didnt work

what specifically happened?

Additionally, what does your crontab look like?

Comment: my crontab */1 * * * * /home/ec2-user/cqlsh_control.sh and also add it try  different combinations crontab */1 * * * * sh /home/ec2-user/cqlsh_control.sh

Comment: In your crontab, add this: `>/tmp/out1 2>/tmp/out2`.  This way you will see the output and errors your script encountered.  Also check your emails, crontab mails out the output from scripts.  Another thing,`*/1` is the same as `*` since crontab does not run more often than once every minute.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47283287/1135424

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582224/shell-script-not-running-via-crontab-but-runs-fine-manually but see also the troubleshooting instructions in the [`crontab` tag wiki](/tags/cron/info).

Answer (score -4):

Edit the crontab and put shell /bin/sh before script like below.

*/1 * * * * /bin/sh /home/ec2-user/cqlsh_control.s

Comment: The OP's script seems to be portable to `/bin/sh` so this is harmless in this case, but as long as the shebang says `/bin/bash` this is *exactly* the wrong advice.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47438573/how-to-protect-virtual-machine-data-from-a-vds-provider